# execute SQL statement using executeQuery in servlet

Tags: java, sql, servlets, prepared-statement, executequery

I have servlet  -

```
@WebServlet("/servlet123")
public class servlet123 extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                String usrID = "111" ; 
            String strAllAccocuntsSQL = "SELECT * (FROM account, account_person) "
                    + "WHERE (account.accountNum = account_person.accountNum"
                    + "AND account_person.personID=? )ORDER BY account.accountNum;";
            PreparedStatement prepareSQL = connection
                    .prepareStatement(strAllAccocuntsSQL);
                        prepareSQL.setString(1, usrID);   
            ResultSet resultWithAccounts = prepareSQL.executeQuery();
    }

}
```

I check all about `connection` and it was OK .

When it reach to the line `ResultSet resultWithAccounts = prepareSQL.executeQuery();` it throws exception -

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'account_person.personID='111' )ORDER BY account.accountNum' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
```

The SQL code of the 2 above tables is -

```
CREATE TABLE  `account_person` (
 `accountNum` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `personID` TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE  `account` (
 `accountNum` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `dateCreated` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `accountName` TEXT,
 `description` TEXT,
 `statusAccount` TEXT,
 `sumOfMoney` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0'
)
```

What wrong in the SQL statement in `prepareSQL` ?

Comment: You're missing a space after `"WHERE (account.accountNum = account_person.accountNum"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect:

```
+ "WHERE (account.accountNum = account_person.accountNum"
+ "AND account_person.personID=? )ORDER BY account.account
```

means you're concatenating `accountNum` and `AND` without an intermediate space. That ties in with the error message.

Comment: Thanks ! I added Brackets in the 2 sides of the AND and it worked out.

Comment: don't overdo it with the parens, you just need spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the pharentesis and add a space:

```
@WebServlet("/servlet123")
public class servlet123 extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                String usrID = "111" ; 
            String strAllAccocuntsSQL = "SELECT * FROM account, account_person "
                    + "WHERE account.accountNum = account_person.accountNum "
                    + "AND account_person.personID=? ORDER BY account.accountNum;";
            PreparedStatement prepareSQL = connection
                    .prepareStatement(strAllAccocuntsSQL);
                        prepareSQL.setString(1, usrID);   
            ResultSet resultWithAccounts = prepareSQL.executeQuery();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the SQL string. You should delete the parenthesis that sorround the FROM section

```
String strAllAccocuntsSQL = "SELECT * FROM account, account_person "
                    + "WHERE (account.accountNum = account_person.accountNum"
                    + "AND account_person.personID=? )ORDER BY account.accountNum;";
```

I would also cancel the ; at the end, if it doesnt work yet